# Integration of a multiplied weibull distribution

Tags: integration, probability-distributions

I am having trouble integrating a weibull function multiplied with a production function.
The expression shortened for integration is as follows:

$$v^{k+2}e^{-\left(\frac{v}{y}\right)^k}$$

I hope you can read the expression and help with the question.

Comment: What is $v$ ? Integration with respect to what ?

Comment: the integration is with respect to v (k and y are constants). v is windspeed.

Comment: Is this homework ?

Comment: No, this is for my bachelor project (in a non-mathematical subject)

Comment: I have edited your post. What is the problem? Maple gives a very complicated expression including the Whittaker M function for the integral.

Comment: The problem is finding the production of a windmill given different constants (k and y), with windspeed from 4 to 14.

Answer (score 1):

First changing variable $v=y \text { }z$, the integral becomes slightly nicer and the final result is
$$-\frac{1}{2} y^{k+3} \Gamma \left(\frac{k+3}{2},\frac{v^2}{y^2}\right)$$