# definite integral of the product of a power- and a Weibull-function

Tags: integration

I am an engineering student who's basic math skills are struggling to solve the definite integral of the product of a power function with a Weibull function:

$$\int_{v_1}^{v_2} A*v^{k+2}* e^{-(v/c)^k} dv$$

The function describes the power output of a wind turbine between wind speeds $v_1$ and $v_2$, both >0. $A$, $k$ and $c$ are constants, all >0.

I did look at [Integration of a multiplied weibull distribution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/718080/integration-of-a-multiplied-weibull-distribution) but cannot make sense of the $\Gamma$ function with two arguments.

Thanks a lot for any help, ideally with a step-by-step guide :-)

Comment: Hej Eric, and thanks for the quick response. As I wrote in my question, this link did not help me (even though it is exactly the same physical problem) because of the 2nd argument in the $\Gamma$-function.

Comment: This is the incomplete gamma function.

Answer (score 0):

First, let $v=ct$
$$I=\int A*v^{k+2}* e^{-(v/c)^k}\, dv=A c^{k+3}\int e^{-t^k} t^{k+2}\,dt$$ Now let $t^k=u$
$$I=\frac{A c^{k+3}}k\int e^{-u} u^{3/k}\,du=-\frac{A c^{k+3}}k \Gamma \left(1+\frac{3}{k},u\right)$$

Comment: Thanks for the response, Claude. Will take my literally BASIC math skills a while to digest that "incomplete" $\Gamma$. Gimme some time, and I'll be back ;-)